# A function which collates data from various API calls. Help on design-pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Help on the **appropriate design pattern** for this.

Program details:

> A scheduled script that fetches all the data from various framework-based API's - `executeSearch('webservice_name')` - ,
>   then, collate the data and pass it to another framework-API - `saveToReportTemplate('report_template_name')` -
>   which persists the collated data to the database.

```
var Report = Report || {};

(function (R) {

    var _data1 = 0,
        _data2 = 0,
        _data3 = 0,
        _data4 = 0;

    function initData() {
        _data1 = 0;
        _data2 = 0;
        _data3 = 0;
        _data4 = 0;
    }

    function fetchData1() {
        //executeSearch is a framework API
        var result = executeSearch('transactions');

        _data1 = result.getValue('transactions.done');
    }

    function fetchData2() {
        //executeSearch is a framework API
        var result = executeSearch('company');

        _data2 = result.getValue('company.investors');
    }

    function fetchData3and4() {
        //executeSearch is a framework API
        var result = executeSearch('employee');
        _data3 =  result.getValue('employee.name');
        _data4 =  result.getValue('employee.salary');
    }

    function populateReport() {
        //framework API
        saveToReportTemplate('some_report_template', _data1, _data2, _data3, _data4);
    }

    R.generateReport = function () {
        initData();
        fetchData1();
        fetchData2();
        fetchData3and4();
    };

})(Report);

//usage
R.generateReport();
```

Need help/advice/criticisms on:

- overall structure of the program
- my usage of private variables and functions
- usage of javascript's closure
- is there anything I can improve?
- any good design patterns for solving this kind of problem?

**Note:** 
There is no way we can implement a new database **table/view** for this, because we are just interacting on external APIs.
Also, there is **no SQL-based method provided** for us to solve such problems.

Comment: Are all your `executeSearch()` and `saveToReportTemplate()` function calls all synchronous/blocking?  Are you sure?  If they are asynchronous, then this structure will not work.  If they are blocking, then this is a pretty unfortunate API to be dealing with.

Comment: @jfriend00 if it is `asynchronous`, can you suggest a different approach? Thanks

Comment: If it is asynchronous, it requires an entirely different design using callbacks or one of the async helper libraries such as promises or the async module.  FYI, code review is supposed to be for "improving code that already works".  Does this code already work or are you just in the stage of looking for design ideas/feedback?

Comment: @jfriend00 the details of the code I presented above, *such as parameter values*, are not to my working code. I am just presenting it in a way majority would understand.

Comment: If any of your data manipulation operations are asynchronous, then this code likely will not work.  You should be able to answer yes or no to that question.  You should bring working code here to code review.  Questions about how to write working code belong in stackOverflow or one of the other programming related forums.

Answer (score 1):

Well, based on what I can get, here's some code that should work. Note that I use native Promises which is ES6 technology. It's handy, but I don't want to have jQuery tagging along. Use a polyfill for older browsers.

```
;(function(ns) {

  ns.generateReport = function(template, executionList) {

    // Because the operations can be async, we use promises instead. This allows
    // us to dictate when and what in the operation we resolve as a value.
    var promises = executionList.map(function(item) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        //Assuming that everything is synchronous, the code most likely looks like this
        var result = search(item.search);
        var data = item.save.map(function(saveItem) {
          result.getValue(saveItem);
        });
        resolve(data);

        //If the operations are aync, then most likely it will look like
        search(item.search, function(result) {
          var data = item.save.map(function(saveItem) {
            result.getValue(saveItem);
          });
          resolve(data);
        });

      });
    });

    // We listen for all of the promises to resolve. When they do, the callback is
    // called with an array of resolved values from the promises we just mapped. They
    // will look like [[1],[2],[3,4]]
    Promises.all(promises).then(function(values) {

      // We concatenate the arrays inside the array using apply and concat. They'll
      // end up like [1,2,3,4]
      var params = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], values);

      // Add in the report template parameter so it'll look like ['template',1,2,3,4]
      params.unshift(template);
      saveToReportTemplate.apply(null, data);
    });

  }

// Uses an existing R or creates one
}(this.R = this.R || {}));

// Sample usage is this.
R.generateReport('report_template', [{
  search: 'transactions',
  save: ['transactions.done']
}, {
  search: 'company',
  save: ['transactions.done']
}, {
  search: 'company.investors',
  save: ['employee.name', 'employee.salary']
}]);
```